# How can I recalculate relative coordinates?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a *div* block:

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

There is an SVG path inside this block with SVG circles. When I do click, I get relative coordinates to `id="container"`. The top-left corner is 0,0.

The SVG element is always full width, height of container. But the SVG has its own view port.

How can I recalculate all points of the circle (x,y) of SVG to relative coordinates of #container?

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2000 1000" width="2000px" height="1000px">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="10" fill="#4285f4"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```

I need to know the relative coordinates of each of circle, relative to the parent `div`.

**JavaScript click is:**

```js
document.getElementById('container').onclick = function clickEvent(e) {
  var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x = e.clientX - rect.left; //x position within the element.
  var y = e.clientY - rect.top; //y position within the element.
  console.log("Left? : " + x + " ; Top? : " + y + ".");
}
```

My attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/3g8un5w1/5/

I want to be able to transform in between position of the circle on canvas and mouse pointer position even when it's scaled via css.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have added JS, viewbox is okay

Comment: It is quite unclear what you want exactly, could you please reformulate your question? Do you want to go from the click's coordinates to the svg's ones? What if your element is inside a <g transform="... ? What are you exactly trying to do? Check if the element is under said coords? In that case there are APIs to do so (e.g elementsFromPoint()).

Comment: I just need offsetX and offsetY of circle relative container. it is all

Comment: @user13314476 but you set it yourself to 100:100. `cx` and `cy` are the relative x,y. If div has padding, add the padding to it.

Comment: No padding, just relative coordinates

Comment: I dont know how to handle if element has scale:
https://jsfiddle.net/3g8un5w1/10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just add `id` to the `circle` itself, and then read it's `cx` and `cy` attribute? If the div `padding` is set to `0`, it should be a relative `x` and `y`. If padding is different, you need to add this padding to the `x` and `y`.

Plase note that it's x,y of center of the circle. Check the example below. At first it reads the `x`,`y` of the circle, then (after 2 seconds) sets it to `0`,`0`. You can see, that it is relative to the `div` border (`red`).

If the div padding would be for example `10px`, that value would still be 100, 100, but relativly to the container, you would have to add that `10`, so it should return `100 + padding`, `100 + padding` (`110`,`110`). And setter should be `110 - padding`, `110 - padding`.

```html
<div id="container" style="padding:0px; border:1px solid red;">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2000 1000" width="2000px" height="1000px">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="10" fill="#4285f4" id="circle"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>

<script>
 console.log('Before:'); 
 console.log(document.getElementById('circle').getAttribute('cx') + ', '+ document.getElementById('circle').getAttribute('cy'));

 setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('After setting to 0,0.');  document.getElementById('circle').setAttribute('cx',0)
  document.getElementById('circle').setAttribute('cy',0)},2000);
</script>
```

---

*EDIT AFTER COMMENT*

Check the fiddle with scale example (based on your comment fiddle):
https://jsfiddle.net/r7ckLfhv/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3g8un5w1/10/

Remove scale, I dont know how to handle it in calculations

Comment: not sure what your comment means, but if you scale it, you don't have to take it in count for setting and getting, but if you click and want to get a mouse pointer position on it, you need to count it in calculation that it will be `cx * scale` and `cy * scale`.

Comment: Maybe this will answer your comment: https://jsfiddle.net/upe2ay6w/ or with dynamic scale calculation: https://jsfiddle.net/r7ckLfhv/